# Serving static files in debug using Django 1.4 is very frustrating

Tags: python, django, static-files

I love Django but getting static files served in development is painfully flakey. I have installed webassets to make the job easier. Basically, my assets are 404'ing with my current configuration but admin assets are fine (?!). My project layout is like this;

```
myapp/
    common/
        static/
            bootstrap/
                img/
                less/
                js/
        templates/
        __init__.py
        assets.py
        urls.py
        models.py
        views.py
    projects/
        templates/
        static/
        __init__.py
        assets.py
        urls.py
        models.py
        views.py
    public/ <- (static files collected here)
settings.py
```

In my settings I have the following values configured

```
__DIR__ = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(__DIR__, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(__DIR__, 'public')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My urls are configured like this;

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^projects/', include('myapp.projects.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.common.urls')),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Again, assets.py looks pretty standard;

```
from django_assets import register, Bundle

js = Bundle(
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js',
    'bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js',
    output='bootstrap/script.js',
    debug=False
)

register('js', js)
```

And my base template is very basic;

```
{% load assets %}
{% assets 'js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}
```

So, when runserver is running, all the js files are bundled into 1  tag with the following url `http://localhost:8000/static/bootstrap/script.js?ed501ad2`. But this 404's with the message "'bootstrap/script.js' could not be found".

If however, I log into the /admin app then all css assets are rendered correctly. I've run collectstatic and verified that the assets does actually live within `public/` directory.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add `django_assets.finders.AssetsFinder` to your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` as is required in the document of django-assets?

http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/webassets/django/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of that - a lesson I should I read the docs more carefully!

Comment: Claude: I don't think a comment like that is helpful. Not really welcoming to the Django community.

Comment: Danny, you are right but I just start to be exasperated with people posting questions on SO without first reading the documentation or Googling, and it's a growing trend. I just don't think this is doing any good to the SO community. In a professional environment anyone would be ashamed asking such questions around and would actually do his homework before wasting his coworkers' time, I don't see where it is ok to do the same here.